# extracting "Falied Password" from "Message" in a log entry.

Tags: regex

I have a log entry as follows:

```
{"TAGS":".source.s_net_unix","SOURCEIP":"1.2.3.4","PROGRAM":"sshd_ext","PRIORITY":"info","PID":"17825","MESSAGE":"Failed password for invalid user admin from 2.3.4.5 port 55327ssh2","HOST_FROM":"server1","HOST":"server1","FACILITY":"auth","DATE":"Dec  2 09:02:01.81220"}
```

I need to extract the "Failed Password" by looking for the "Message" in the string. How can I do this using String utilities or writing a regular expression?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unix would be best, I guess SED or AWK would be the fastest. other than that any approach would be fine: java/javascript etc.

Comment: have a look at regex101.com and try ...

Comment: If that's the case, I'd say your question is either too broad (a complete answer would require listing how to solve this using every possible language/tool in existence) or it is opinion based (a good answer would require making a judgement call over which language/tool is best).  You should ask your question targeting a specific technology (and tag it as such).  If you want to know how to solve it using multiple technologies so that you can compare them, I would suggest asking the question multiple times--once per technology.  However, it's still not great because it shows little effort.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, why would you use REGEX on a parsable format ? REGEX is a really powerful "weapon" when dealing with plain text but there are more specialized tools and libraries for parsable formats. You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

In your case, i'm pretty sure that there is a JSON library for your programming language (some have JSON libs included by default).

If the JSON library don't seems a good idea for you, you can try this regex

```
MESSAGE":"([^"]*)"
```